# Load content of external header on other page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've only started working on my website and I've already run into a little hiccup, for some reason a script that I use doesn't work anymore and I can't find any fixes, there's nothing in the chrome console or any useful error information.

I was hoping you guys could help me out.

I'm simply trying to load a piece of a different HTML page onto my Index page.

Usually I run this script, and it should take the `#nav` div from the `header.html` and put it into the `header` below the script.

*Index.html:*

```
<!--added scripts-->
<script src="jquery/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
<!-- Css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Sjvklusbedrijf.css">

<!--script-->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#header").load("header.html #nav");
        alert("test");
    });
</script>

</head>
<body>
<header id="header">

</header>
```

*requested script:*

```
<div id="#nav">
<div class="logodiv"></div>
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="foto.html">Foto's</a></li>
    <li><a href="garantie.html">Garantie</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

I'm using jquery and have loaded it thusly: `<script src="jquery/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>` and if I put an alert in the `doc.ready` script it pops up but it doesn't load the required data

I'm running on localhost but that shouldn't be a problem for jquery

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It did not work the first time because `<div id="#nav">` should be `<div id="nav">`.

Answer (score 0):

okay somehow it decided to work but I don't really get why.

I changed some things:

*index:*

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#header").load("header.html nav");
    });
</script>

</head>
<body>
<!--header-->
<header id="header" class="header">

</header>
```

*required script:*

```
<nav>
<img src="fotos/test" alt="logo"/>
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="foto.html">Foto's</a></li>
    <li><a href="garantie.html">Garantie</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```